# Create ListView on right side of Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, listview

According to the following picture:

I want something like this

[image: layout]

the `ListView` is not a `NavigationDrawer`, it's a part of the `Activity`. 
Items the `ListView` are columns of a database and when user selected Each of them, on the left side(`Activity`), other fields of that column should be displayed.
How can I do this?

Comment: Use the concept of fragments

Comment: try to do first. Then whenever you have a specific issue you ask here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @Budius Thanks for the hint,but what was wrong with my question!!?

Comment: you show no effort in trying to solve the problem for yourself and it's just asking for someone else to solve it for you. Usually you should show what have you tried and specific issue you had while trying it. Asking for a code for you to copy and paste is not cool.

Comment: @Budius you are right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"                       
            android:layout_weight="1">
           //Your UI
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"                       
            android:layout_weight="1">
           //Your ListView
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

So your layout will have fragments one a left fragment and one a right one

XML

```
    <LinearLayout
        orientation:horizontal>
        <FrameLayout
        id=leftFragment
        weight=1/>
        <FrameLayout
        id=rightFragment
        weight=1/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Java Code

```
FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
fm.replace(R.id.leftFragment,new LeftFragment());
fm.commit();
```

Similarly for Right Fragment

Comment: You can have a list view in Right Fragment and any layout in left that makes your left layout Dynamic

Comment: of course,but problam is that my reputation is less than 15  so i can't upvote :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use a LinearLayout with Horizontal orientation, then have two layout, one for the left side of the screen and one for the right side of the screen (with your `ListView`). Then you should use the `layout_weight` attribute for each layout by declaring like 0.7 for the right one (`ListView`) and 0.3 for the left one, it should looks like your picture